# Loop doesn't end

Tags: c, for-loop

```
int main(void){

    int range = 0, i = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of digits of the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &range);

    int a[range];
    int b[range];

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    for(i = 0; i < range; i++){
            scanf("%1d", &a[i]);
    }

    replace(a, b, range);

    swap(&b[0],&b[range]);

    printf("Output: ");
    for(i = range; i > 0; i--){
            printf("%d", b[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void replace(int *a, int *b, int n){
    int *p;
    int temp;

    for(p = a; p < a + n; p++){
            temp = ((*p + 6) % 10) / 10;
            p = b;
            *p = temp;

    }
 }

  void swap(int *p, int *q)
 {
    int temp;

    temp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
 }
```

My problem is with the first for loop, the loop seems to just keep taking in input and doesn't end. I tried putting a print statement before the replace method and it didn't print so I knew the problem was with the for loop. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check the value within `range` after calling `scanf()`?

Comment: The second for loop looks like it is causing the problem. Also, you shoud use `int i = 0` not `i = 0`

Comment: You've not got any newlines in the printing you do show, so the chances are you don't know where the code gets stuck.  Output does not usually appear until you print a newline.  You've not shown your sample data.  You've not shown what value you get for `range` — print what you read; if there's a difference between what you thought you entered and what the program thinks you entered, you can head off problems early.  Print each digit back as it is entered.  Check the return value from `scanf()`.  In this context, if the return value is not 1, you've got problems.

Comment: @EvanCarslake No! He already declared `i`.

Comment: I suspect you're overrunning your arrays. Try including a printf in the loop that tells you the value of range and i, each time through. See if they stay consistent.

Comment: @Quest yes, but it is easier to read if the i is declared at the start of the for loop. Thus making it easier to find the problemo.

Comment: Note that the `swap` line — `swap(&b[0],&b[range]);` — definitely accesses data out of the bounds of the `b` array, unless the `swap` function does something inscrutable like subtract 1 from the second pointer before using it.

Comment: @EvanCarslake yes, but this is his own decision. Saying "do this" without tellin him why just don't make any sense. I agree it's harder to read but if he chose this way, let him go, At least don't say "it should be" just because you are doing it that way

Comment: I tried your program, adding `#include <stdio.h>`, in GCC. It doesn't know where to get swap and replace, so I commented them out. It works for me, in the sense that it terminates properly and when I give it 4, 1234, it produces 1000. I think you'll have to provide a better example. Also, if the problem is in the first few lines, can you cut the example down to that?

Comment: As well as the `swap()` call working out of bounds, your output loop is accessing data out of bounds.

Comment: I didn't think those two were the issue. They're just undefined for me, so I commented them out. The issue, according to you, is appearing earlier in your code. But I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain why `replace()` is broken, and to explain why the printing loop is broken.  Programming is an exacting art; a single mistake can render the program useless (though you can often get away with a few small bugs — but the output may be incorrect).

Comment: Don't destroy key information from the question after you've received an answer that addresses that information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The `replace()` function is a disaster

You've now posted the `replace` function and it is a disaster.

```
void replace(int *a, int *b, int n)
{
    int *p;
    int temp;

    for (p = a; p < a + n; p++)
    {
        temp = ((*p + 6) % 10) / 10;
        p = b;
        *p = temp;
    }
}
```

You attempt to iterate over the array `a` by making `p` point to each element in turn.  But you then, in the body of the loop, assign `b` to `p`, which places it outside the array `a`, which means all bets are off.  It's not clear whether `b` is less than `a + n` or not — it simply isn't defined.  But given that you get an infinite loop, it probably is, so your code goes reading from and writing to the same couple of locations over and over (`b[0]`, `b[1]`) and `p` never progresses nearer to `a + n`.

A simple fix uses indexes:

```
void replace(int *a, int *b, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        b[i] = ((a[i] + 6) % 10) / 10;
}
```

If you want to use pointers, then:

```
void replace(int *a, int *b, int n)
{
    for (int *p = a; p < a + n; p++)
        *b++ = ((*p + 6) % 10) / 10;
}
```

Note that the expression evaluates to zero.  The modulo 10 operation produces a value in the range 0..9 (or -9..+9), and that divided by 10 is always 0.  You'll need to work on that expression.

## The call to `swap()` is broken

You have:

```
swap(&b[0], &b[range]);
```

This definitely accesses data out of the bounds of the `b` array.  To be safe, you need to use:

```
swap(&b[0], &b[range-1]);
```

## Your output loop is broken

You have:

```
printf("Output: ");
for(i = range; i > 0; i--){
        printf("%d", b[i]);
}
```

You need to avoid accessing `b[range]` again, and you need to output a newline at the end:

```
printf("Output: ");
for (i = range; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%d", b[i-1]);
putchar('\n');
```

## The input code works

The input code works, as demonstrated by this minimal adaptation of what you've got:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int range = 0, i = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of digits in the number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &range) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops 1\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Number of digits: %d\n", range);

    int a[range];

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    for (i = 0; i < range; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%1d", &a[i]) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Oops 2\n");
            return 2;
        }
        printf("Digit %d: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("Reversed input: ");
    for (i = range; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%2d", a[i-1]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The 'reversed input' loop is an adaptation of the 'output' loop in the question — bug-fixed to avoid accessing the array out of bounds, and using `a` instead of `b`.  The error messages are very uninformative (not suitable for production work), but they're adequate to identify which statement caused an error while you're debugging.

Example run:

```
$ ./example-input
Enter the number of digits in the number: 12
Number of digits: 12
Enter the number: 1234 5678 9101112
Digit 0: 1
Digit 1: 2
Digit 2: 3
Digit 3: 4
Digit 4: 5
Digit 5: 6
Digit 6: 7
Digit 7: 8
Digit 8: 9
Digit 9: 1
Digit 10: 0
Digit 11: 1
Reversed input:  1 0 1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
$
```

Now, adapt this into your program and see where the problem really is.

---

## Working code

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void swap(int *a, int *b);
static void replace(int *a, int *b, int n);

int main(void)
{
    int range = 0, i = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of digits in the number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &range) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Number of digits: %d\n", range);

    int a[range];
    int b[range];

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    for (i = 0; i < range; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%1d", &a[i]) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Oops 2\n");
            return 2;
        }
        printf("Digit %d: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("Reversed input: ");
    for (i = range; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%2d", a[i-1]);
    putchar('\n');

    replace(a, b, range);
    swap(&b[0], &b[range-1]);

    printf("Output: ");
    for (i = range; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%2d", b[i-1]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}

static void swap(int *p, int *q)
{
    int t = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = t;
}

static void replace(int *a, int *b, int n)
{
    for (int *p = a; p < a + n; p++)
        *b++ = ((*p + 6) % 10);
}
```

#### Example output

```
$ ./example-input
Enter the number of digits in the number: 9
Number of digits: 9
Enter the number: 123 456 789
Digit 0: 1
Digit 1: 2
Digit 2: 3
Digit 3: 4
Digit 4: 5
Digit 5: 6
Digit 6: 7
Digit 7: 8
Digit 8: 9
Reversed input:  9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Output:  7 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 5
$
```

Comment: When I wrote my answer, you hadn't posted the `swap` and `replace` functions.  You've got bugs in your call to `swap` and in your output loop.  You are definitively accessing data out of bounds in those.  That probably shouldn't affect the loops stopping, but you are invoking _undefined behaviour_ (a technical term from the C standard — and something to be avoided at all costs), so the compiler can do whatever it likes and the result is OK according to the standard.

Comment: Your output loop printed the digits in reverse order, so I left mine doing the same.  I get `5 8 4 8 4` from my program, which is the reverse of what you wanted.  If you want the digits in normal order, simple replace the output loop with `for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) printf("%2d", b[i]); putchar('\n');`.  The spaces appear because I used `%2d` to print each single digit in 2 columns.  Use `%d` if you want them all adjacent to each other.  I've no idea why your code is not producing the `5`; mine does.  Incidentally, I just checked that the code handles 36 digits; it did.